# How to handle service when Orientation is changed

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I am making a music player app for learning purposes but I am stuck at the point where the user decides to change the orientation of the device, my app always recreates which is bad, I have managed to have all other data saved and restored using `onRestoreInstanceState` but I cannot think of a good approach with the `musicplayer service`, below is part of my code, it is a lot of code so i will focus on the problem

```
public class ManagerActivty extends AppCompatActivity{

 //music player service object
 private MusicService musicService;

 //boolean to keep track of musicservice state
 private boolean musicBound = Boolean.FALSE;

  //Music service connection object
    private ServiceConnection musicServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        if(!instanceSaved) {
            MusicService.MusicBinder binder = (MusicService.MusicBinder) iBinder;
            musicService = binder.getService();
            musicService.setOnSongChangeListener(ManagerActivty.this);
            musicService.setOnPlayerStateChangedListener(ManagerActivty.this);
            new loadSongAsync().execute();
            musicBound = Boolean.TRUE;
            System.out.println("Music Service Connected");

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        musicBound = Boolean.FALSE;
    }
};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manager_activty);
 }

//method to bind music service with my activity
 private void bindMusicService()
{
    playMusicIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
    bindService(playMusicIntent, musicServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    startService(playMusicIntent);
    System.out.println("Binder Called");

}



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    //launch binder    
    bindMusicService();
}


  @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
 //stop service connection
    if (playMusicIntent != null) {
        stopGuiUpdates();
        unbindService(musicServiceConnection);
        stopService(playMusicIntent);
        musicService = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

}




 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    System.out.println("Saved Instances");
    outState.putBoolean(Constant.IS_MEDIA_PLAYING_PLAYING, musicService.isPlaying());
    outState.putInt(Constant.MEDIA_PLAYER_POSITION, musicService.getMediaPlayer().getCurrentPosition());
    outState.putBoolean(Constant.IS_MUSIC_REPLAY, musicService.isReplay());

}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("Retrieving Instances");

      //if null try to re-bind service
    if(musicService == null) {
        bindMusicService();

    }


}
```

this code gives me a nullpointerexception when I try to access the `musicservice` object after orientation changed, anyone who has dealt with this before please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare the config changes to the `<activity>` tag in the **App Manifest.xml** file

> android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

This is the complete list of the attributes that you can set in `<activity>` tag in **Manifest.xml**

> ```
> <activity android:allowEmbedded=["true" | "false"]
>           android:allowTaskReparenting=["true" | "false"]
>           android:alwaysRetainTaskState=["true" | "false"]
>           android:autoRemoveFromRecents=["true" | "false"]
>           android:banner="drawable resource"
>           android:clearTaskOnLaunch=["true" | "false"]
>           android:configChanges=["mcc", "mnc", "locale",
>                                  "touchscreen", "keyboard", "keyboardHidden",
>                                  "navigation", "screenLayout", "fontScale",
>                                  "uiMode", "orientation", "screenSize",
>                                  "smallestScreenSize"]
>           android:documentLaunchMode=["intoExisting" | "always" |
>                                   "none" | "never"]
>           android:enabled=["true" | "false"]
>           android:excludeFromRecents=["true" | "false"]
>           android:exported=["true" | "false"]
>           android:finishOnTaskLaunch=["true" | "false"]
>           android:hardwareAccelerated=["true" | "false"]
>           android:icon="drawable resource"
>           android:label="string resource"
>           android:launchMode=["multiple" | "singleTop" |
>                               "singleTask" | "singleInstance"]
>           android:maxRecents="integer"
>           android:multiprocess=["true" | "false"]
>           android:name="string"
>           android:noHistory=["true" | "false"]  
>           android:parentActivityName="string" 
>           android:permission="string"
>           android:process="string"
>           android:relinquishTaskIdentity=["true" | "false"]
>           android:screenOrientation=["unspecified" | "behind" |
>                                      "landscape" | "portrait" |
>                                      "reverseLandscape" | "reversePortrait" |
>                                      "sensorLandscape" | "sensorPortrait" |
>                                      "userLandscape" | "userPortrait" |
>                                      "sensor" | "fullSensor" | "nosensor" |
>                                      "user" | "fullUser" | "locked"]
>           android:stateNotNeeded=["true" | "false"]
>           android:taskAffinity="string"
>           android:theme="resource or theme"
>           android:uiOptions=["none" | "splitActionBarWhenNarrow"]
>           android:windowSoftInputMode=["stateUnspecified",
>                                        "stateUnchanged", "stateHidden",
>                                        "stateAlwaysHidden", "stateVisible",
>                                        "stateAlwaysVisible", "adjustUnspecified",
>                                        "adjustResize", "adjustPan"] >   
>     . . .
> </activity>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

On everytime the user rotates his phone the onCreate() method is called. I would suggest to add this line to your xml

android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

Also, learn somethings about the Parcelable interface.